# Which probability rule should be applied here?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I would like to know how to answer a certain question, so that I can learn the how to apply probability rules properly. At the moment, I am unable to get in-person assistance, and since I am relatively new to probability, I am not sure what terminology to use to better describe my question other than that it is a homework question.

The question is as follows:

The probability that there are *at least i* apples in a basket is given by $Pr(A_i) = 0.8^i$

The probability that there are exactly *i* apples can be expressed as $q \times p^i$. **Q: What are the values for *p* and *q*?**

My working is as follows:

$Pr(\texttt{Exactly i apples})=Pr(A_i \cap A^\complement_{i+1})$

This right-hand side of the equation means the event that there are at least $i$ apples but there are **not** at least $i+1$ apples - meaning there are **exactly** *i* apples.

I'll need to be able to expand the intersection if I am to get anywhere further. As far as I know, the only rules that can expand an intersection like this are:

- $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A|B) \times Pr(B) $
- $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cup B)$
- $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) \times Pr(B)$ **only if** $A$ and $B$ are *independent*

I cannot use the first rule, because I do not know the conditional probability $Pr(A_i|A_{i+1})$ or $Pr(A_{i+1}|A_i)$.

I cannot use the second rule, because I do not know the the union $Pr(A_i \cup\ A_{i+1})$, and cannot find it through addition because $A_i$ and $A_{i+1}$ are not disjoint.

I cannot use the third rule, because $A_i$ and $A_{i+1}$ are not independent. This is obvious because if there are at least *i+1* apples, then there must also be at least *i* apples.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be amazing!

Comment: I think you are over complicating matters.  The probability that there are exactly $3$ apples is the probability that there are at least $3$ minus the probability that there are at least $4$.

Comment: "at least i" = "i or i+1 or i+2  ..."  = complementary event of "1, 2... i-1".

Comment: Try using the geometric distribution. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution Using this distribution since p=0.8 and q=1-p we have q=0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lulu has given the simplest approach, but you can apply your second rule if you wish

You do know $P(A_i \cup A_{i+1}^C)$ which is the probability there are at least $i$ or there are fewer than $i+1$ - this must be the case, so the probability must be $1$

So   $$P(A_i \cap A_{i+1}^C)=P(A_i )+P(A_{i+1}^C)-P(A_i \cup A_{i+1}^C) = 0.8^i+(1-0.8^{i+1}) - 1$$ which simplifies to lulu's answer

It can be rewritten as $(1-0.8)\times 0.8^i$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed, and it makes sense, too.